# Responsive bootstrap carousel (not working)

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a responsive bootstrap carousel. it looks fine in full view but when i try to decrease the screen size the carousel items adjusts them selves below the previous. I want them to display as single item in carousel. attaching the screens and code. Please check and let me know what i am missing out. Would appreciate any help

[Full Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wetlk.png)
[Small Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85C09.jpg)

```css
/* carousel */
.media-carousel 
{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* Previous button  */
.media-carousel .carousel-control
{
     background: #37873a!important;
color:white;
}
.media-carousel .carousel-control:hover 
{
color:white;
}
/* Previous button  */
.media-carousel .carousel-control.left 
{
  left: -12px;
  background-image: none;
  background: #37873a;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
  height: 40px;
  width : 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
/* Next button  */
.media-carousel .carousel-control.right 
{
  right: -12px !important;
  background-image: none;
  background: #37873a;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
  height: 40px;
  width : 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
/* Changes the position of the indicators */
.media-carousel .carousel-indicators 
{
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: -19px;
}
/* Changes the colour of the indicators */
.media-carousel .carousel-indicators li 
{
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
.media-carousel .carousel-indicators .active 
{
  background: #333333;
}
.media-carousel img
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<section class="divider bg-light promotion-section">
    <div class="container pt-10 pb-10">
        <div class="row">
           <div class='col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12'>
             <h3 class="text-center">Meet Our Team</h3>
      <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>        
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>        
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>     
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
             <h3 class="text-center">Video Gallery</h3>
      <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media2">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="~/images/user.jpg"></a>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media2" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media2" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Owl carousel, fully customisable.